# how can I triming a field data on a special character (please see example)

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table that has an activity record written by one of the integration we have and I want to know if there is a way to edit the field data down to so I can report on it (see example below)

text1|text2|text3

all I want to have in one column is the text3 part of the string. The character limit is not consistent threw all the data but the separation character of | is

any help is great appreciated

Comment: What is your actual database?  MySQL?  SQL Server?  Something else?

Comment: SQL Server 2014